# JVM Life cycle?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I need a step by step explanation of what is exactly happening when we call `java -jar JAR_FILE.jar` until the JVM finishes its job and returns.

How the stage becomes ready for JVM to be run on the host machine?
What functions are called? What threads are created?
What happens when JVM is going to shutdown?

Comment: the java language specification document can be a good starting point...

Comment: @marathon- I've seen Java specification, but I need a more clear one! it goes deep into details.

Comment: You can have a look at this book: https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_performance_the_java_series. Chapter 3 provides some insights about the JVM internals.

Comment: Also study the JNI interfaces, as these are the basic "tools" used to construct and control the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my list of steps it is very high level.

1. JVM boots up and setups up the various memory areas that the GC will be managing, it will also setup some system threads
2. Look the jar file manifest to determine the class that has the main method to load
3. Load the main class and verify that the byte code in the just loaded class is correct and not doing anything illegal.
4. resolve what classes are needed by the class being loaded and load those classes each class being loaded goes through step 3 and 4
5. Find the the byte code for the main method and execute it.

This is a really simplified list, full details are much more specific and are probably dependent on the JVM implementation.

You might want to look at this book Inside the Java Virtual Machine 2nd Edition for a something more readable than the JVM spec http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/

Comment: Thanks dude! But I need more details on step 1 :)